# How to increase Physical Memory for Modal Analysis in ANSYS

Tags: modal-analysis, ansys-apdl

I am facing following error while attempting to run Modal Analysis:

There is not enough memory for the Distributed Sparse Matrix Solver to
proceed using the out-of-core memory mode.  The total memory required
by all processes = 4790 MB.  The total physical memory that is
available on the system = 3365 MB.  Please decrease the model size, or
run this model on another system with more physical memory.

I have increased page file size by going to "Windows Performance" and setting paging file allocation to more than 20000 MB. Also I have increased Memory allocation of "Total 6k" & "Database 2k".

Still error appears...

However at corser mesh, the memory error does not appear but then the results are less accurate

Comment: Windows is going to have a difficult time swapping data... all the time. If you can use symmetry (1/2, 1/4, 1/8) I would try that and compare results to those already calculated. You might even just report the results versus element count and indicate percent error between runs. Add more RAM?

Comment: Physical memory = RAM. If you are running a 32 bit application, these days you're more likely to run out of address space...